# Where does Query Store stand and where does it store execution plan, runtime statistics information?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, sql-server-2016, sql-execution-plan, sql-query-store

I would like to know that where does Query Store stand and store execution plan, runtime statistics  information? I researched how does SQL Server compile, execute query and in which part Query Store works and how it works. But I could not get enough information where it stand and for its Max Size feature where it store all information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If query store is enabled SQL stores the information in [system db views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/how-query-store-collects-data?view=sql-server-ver15) you can query these [views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/best-practice-with-the-query-store?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#Configure) to retrieve the configuration and status of query store.

```
SELECT actual_state_desc, desired_state_desc, current_storage_size_mb,
     max_storage_size_mb, readonly_reason
    FROM sys.database_query_store_options;
```

or to see all

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_query_store_options;
```